# emacs custom command line arguments

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to be able to tell emacs to open files in read-only mode
or in auto-revert mode by providing a command line argument, for example:

```
emacs -A file1 file2 file3 ...
```

should open files in auto-revert mode

```
emacs -R file1 file2 file3 ...
```

should open files in read-only mode

I have found the following:

```
(defun open-read-only (switch)
  (let ((file1 (expand-file-name (pop command-line-args-left))))
  (find-file-read-only file1)))
(add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("-R" . open-read-only))

(defun open-tail-revert (switch)
  (let ((file1 (expand-file-name (pop command-line-args-left))))
  (find-file-read-only file1)
  (auto-revert-tail-mode t)))
(add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("-A" . open-tail-revert))
```

the problem with this is that it only works for a single file at a time.

i.e.

```
emacs -R file1
```

works, but

```
emacs -R file1 file2
```

does not work.

How to change the functions above so that they could 
open several files simultaneously in the specified modes? 
Could someone suggest a simple and elegant solution?

Answer (score 4):

Just consume items from `command-line-args-left` until the next switch:

```
(defun open-read-only (switch)
  (while (and command-line-args-left
              (not (string-match "^-" (car command-line-args-left))))
    (let ((file1 (expand-file-name (pop command-line-args-left))))
      (find-file-read-only file1))))
```

BTW, notice that this will open each file relative to the directory of the previous one.